# Sublime - ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, import, module

I'm VERY new to python and sublime. I'm currently watching training videos and following along. I ran into a number of issues with sublime but can't get pass this one. I'm getting the error when trying to import a module into the interpreter i created during training. The `wiper.py` file is located in `Users/marcus/Documents/Scripts/`. I've printed the current path below. Can someone help me?

```
>>> import wiper 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named wiper
>>> print ('PATH = ' + os.environ['PATH'])
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/marcus/Documents/Scripts//.rvm/bin:de here
```

Some additional information. i imported sys and ran sys.path and got this information. i don't know if this is helpful or not.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: Your `PATH` looks a little unusual to me. Did you intend for `/Users/marcus/Documents/Scripts` and `/.rvm/bin` to not be separated by a colon? And what does the `de here` at the end do? (disclaimer: I'm a Windows user, so I'm not used to this particular syntax)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to add `/Users/marcus/Documents/Scripts` to your *Python* module search path. `PATH` is only for your shell to find executables, not Python modules.

You can set the [`PYTHONPATH` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH):

```
export PYTHONPATH='/Users/marcus/Documents/Scripts'
```

You can set that environment variable just for your Sublime Text project; in your project settings add:

```
"build_systems":
[
    {
        "name": "Python",
        "shell_cmd": "python -u \"$file\"",
        "env": {
            "PYTHONPATH": "/Users/marcus/Documents/Scripts"
        },
        "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
        "selector": "source.python"
    }
]
```

or use the same type of settings to create a global [build system](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html#options).

Another approach would be for your script to add the path programatically by inserting into `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/marcus/Documents/Scripts')
import wiper
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. When I try to save your suggested code for the build system sublime highlights in red the : after "file_regex" and when i try to save it sublime says unexpected character being that : after file_regex. Any ideas?

Comment: @markluv: there was a comma missing before `"file_regex"`; added now with apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this on MacOs. What I found is sublime was using v3.9 while the py-environment default was at v3.8.

Installing the library with the specific python version which sublime was using solved the issue.

E.g.

**> python3.8 -m pip install -U readerwriterlock**
Requirement already up-to-date: readerwriterlock in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: typing-extensions in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from readerwriterlock) (3.7.4.3)

**> python3.9 -m pip install -U readerwriterlock**
Collecting readerwriterlock
Using cached readerwriterlock-1.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from readerwriterlock) (3.7.4.3)
Installing collected packages: readerwriterlock
Successfully installed readerwriterlock-1.0.8
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.1; however, version 21.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

**> which python3**
/Users/arun.kaushik/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3

**> python3**
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02)
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin